# Split ip address out of list or string

Tags: python-3.x, string, list, split, ip

I am trying to analyze a logfile in python 3.7. I have entries like this:

```
2020-07-13 18:05:43.332880;sshd;1144;logon root from 192.168.179.9 started

2020-07-13 18:10:12.332880;sshd;1854;logon admin from 192.168.179.3 finished

2020-07-14 03:17:02.332880;sshd;1169;logon admin from 10.0.1.5 failed

2020-07-14 03:19:30.332880;sshd;1297;logon root from 10.0.1.3 failed
```

I read the file into python as such:

```
def readLog(fname):
    """ Read log-events from file """
    lines = []
    file = open("<pathname>", encoding = 'utf-8')
    lines = file.read()#.split('\n')
    file.close()

return lines # returns the logfile
```

I need to get a summary as output looking like this:

```
day:2020-07-01,prog:SSH,success:12,failure:13,ip:1.2.3.4
```

So the goal is to get all info such as the date, amount of failed and succsessful attempts for each different ip address.
I tried splitting but I can't get it to work, I have tried a few approaches but with no result yet. I tried:

```
    events = readLog(logFname)
    for event in events:
            event.split(" ",4)
            print(event)
            #ipList=[]
            #ipList.append(event)
```

The ip is after the 4th space, but I want only the ip so only from the 4th space untill the 5th. Not sure how to do that either. But I need to get the split to works first, then I can try to solve the details. I looked around on the internet and found a few solutions (see sources below) but I haven't been able to use them correctly or get them to work. I tried at something like this:

```
events = readLog(logFname)
for event in events:
    [i.split(" ", 4) for i in event]
```

Hope someone can help me with this,thank you.
Sources:

[How to split elements of a list?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6696027/how-to-split-elements-of-a-list)

[Python Recognizing An IP In A String](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/22723360/python-recognizing-an-ip-in-a-string)

http://www.datasciencemadesimple.com/remove-spaces-in-python/

Comment: You could try using [regex](https://docs.python.org/3/library/re.html#re.findall) to extract the IP address and if the request succeeded or failed from the log information

Answer (score 0):

Doing this should give you ip, you can repeat with different indices to get different data from the string

events = readLog(logFname)
for event in events:
[i.split(" ")[4] for i in event]

Comment: Thank you, that clears out the errors I had in my version of this. But for some reason it still doesn't work. No matter what split I am using I keep getting this as output, which is the same as the input:  2020-07-13 18:05:43.332880;sshd;1144;logon root from 192.168.179.9 started.  My splits don't seem to have effect. I have no clue why.